# Using a for loop to create a new list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I have a list of strings and would like to use a for loop to change the strings and create a new list.

```
oldList = ['AAA','BBB','CCC']

for i in range(len(oldList)):

    newList = []
    add1 = 'a_'
    add2 = '_z'

    newStr = add1 + oldList[i] + add2

    newList.append(newStr)
```

The list 'newList' should contain all the strings on the old list plus the amendments (i.e. ['a_AAA_z', 'a_BBB_z', 'a_CCC_z']). However, it only contains the last string (i.e. ['a_CCC_z']).

What am I missig here? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: put `newList = []` outside for loop

Comment: moved that newList outside loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare the output list outside of the loop. It can be simplified, by the way:

```
newList = []
for ele in oldList:
    add1 = 'a_'
    add2 = '_z'
    newStr = add1 + ele + add2
    newList.append(newStr)
```

Or we can simplify even further if we use a list comprehension and formatted strings, as suggested by @AnnZen

```
newList = [f"a_{ele}_z" for ele in oldList]
```

Comment: @AnnZen yes! that's a nice suggestion, I'll update my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of list should be outside the loop

```
oldList = ['AAA','BBB','CCC']
newList = []

for i in range(len(oldList)):
    # should not declare newList inside for loop
    #newList = []
    add1 = 'a_'
    add2 = '_z'

    newStr = add1 + oldList[i] + add2

    newList.append(newStr)
print(newList)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use formatted strings and list comprehensions:

```
oldList = ['AAA','BBB','CCC']
newList = [f'a_{s}_z' for s in oldList]
print(newList)
```

Output:

```
['a_AAA_z', 'a_BBB_z', 'a_CCC_z']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list comp:

```
oldList = ['AAA','BBB','CCC']
newList = ['a_' + i + '_z' for i in oldList]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `newList` outside the for-loop. If you declare it inside the for-loop, then on each iteration of the for-loop you're reassigning the variable `newList` to be equal to an empty list, and hence you lose your data from the previous iterations (leaving you with only the data from the last iteration.

Here's your code with the declaration fixed:

```
oldList = ['AAA','BBB','CCC']
newList = []

for i in range(len(oldList)):
    add1 = 'a_'
    add2 = '_z'

    newStr = add1 + oldList[i] + add2

    newList.append(newStr)
```

and here's an even simplified version:

```
oldList = ['AAA','BBB','CCC']
newList = ['a_' + str + '_z' for str in oldList]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the `newList` outside the for loop otherwise it will get initialized at every iteration.
This code snippet might help.

```
oldList = ['AAA','BBB','CCC']
newList = []

for i in range(len(oldList)):
   add1 = 'a_'
   add2 = '_z'

   newStr = add1 + oldList[i] + add2

   newList.append(newStr)
print(newList)
```